# Create function for use in views and controllers

Tags: php, function, laravel

Im relative new in laravel, before use laravel I used a file functions.php with all functions that I use in my projects (create slugs, format dates, etc).

where I can create my own functions in laravel to use in controllers and views like myfunction($data) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app/Http directory, create a helpers.php file to add your functions

Within composer.json, in the autoload block, add:
"files": ["app/Http/helpers.php"].

On command line run "composer dump-autoload"

Answer (score 0):

Use the Laravel composer example, where it creates some helper files:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
        "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Illuminate\\": "src/Illuminate/"
    }
},
```

Edit your composer.json file, where you could create a helper in the App folder

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php",
    ],
    ...
},
```

Then you just have to execute

```
 composer dumpautoload
```

To tell composer to load it automatically.